# Django - Combining Multiple Variables

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a blog. On its first page I want to show 4 random blog posts & 6 latest blog posts!

Here's what I did:

```
# 4 random posts
data1 = sorted(Blog.objects.all(), key=lambda x: random.random())[:4] 

# 6 latest posts (excluding the random ones)
data2 = Blog.objects.exclude(id__in=data1).order_by('-id')[:6]

# all blogs
results = list(chain(data1, data2))
```

But the above code is raising an error: `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Blog'`.

When I remove `.exclude(id__in=data1)` from `data2` everything is working fine, but I need it in order to prevent duplicates.

How can we fix that? Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id__in` expects a collection of integers, because the `id` column is of integer type. So you'll have to extract the `id` column from `data1`:

```
id__in=[post.id for post in data1]
```

EDIT: This is necessary because you converted the QuerySet from the first line into a Python list. However, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in and `order_by('?')` - it's better not to convert `QuerySet`s into lists sooner than you have to, since composing `QuerySet`s directly will generate SQL that doesn't fetch the entire table into memory.

Comment: Thank You, Thank You, Thank You! Working perfectly fine now :)

Comment: No worries, glad it worked :) By the way, I have a feeling that it might be possible to use `id__in=query_set` if `query_set` is a Django QuerySet and not a simple Python `list` as it is here (because you used `sorted`). It's probably better to use `QuerySets` throughout to avoid fetching every single blog post in the table, if possible. (Although it would only matter if you had a large number of posts, of course.)